# Debugging JDT Core BatchCompiler inside IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea, eclipse-jdt

I am trying to debug the Eclipse JDT Core BatchCompiler.

I have downloaded the git repository, and imported the POM into IntelliJ IDEA, but when I try to debug the file it is supposedly not found.

See screenshots of the Debug Configuration, and of the File opened in IntelliJ.  I'm befuddled.  Any ideas?  TIA!

[image: IntelliJ Debug Configuration]
[image: IntelliJ Java File]

Answer (score 1):

IntelliJ is correct. The class is not there. You need to mark `batch` directory as Sources Root. You probably need to import from Eclipse project, not Maven...

Comment: OK, that's progress, thanks, so I up-voted your answer, but now I get a bunch of errors like `Error:(18, 45) java: package org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.env does not exist`.  Am I supposed to do this for each package?

Comment: Try reimporting the project from Eclipse.

Comment: That doesn't work either.  I get errors when trying to import the Eclipse project, saying `Unable to procesed. Duplicate names found: org.eclipse.jdt.core`

Comment: You need to uncheck modules with duplicate names/check only modules you want in the project wizard.

Comment: OK, progress again, thanks.  now I get a dialog to configure path variables for the following: `CONVERTER_JCL15_LIB, CONVERTER_JCL15_SRC, CONVERTER_JCL17_LIB, CONVERTER_JCL17_SRC, CONVERTER_JCL18_LIB, CONVERTER_JCL18_SRC, JCL15_LIB, JCL15_SRC, JCL18_LIB, JCL18_SRC, JCL_LIB, JCL_SRC` does that mean that I need those libraries locally and point to them?  That's the reason I was trying to import the Maven project in the first place.  Thank you for your help!

Comment: You need to not import *test* modules, needless to say, the whole thing just sucks. I was able to compile these modules: `org.eclipse.jdt.annotation,
org.eclipse.jdt.annotation_v1,
org.eclipse.jdt.apt.core,
org.eclipse.jdt.apt.pluggable.core,
org.eclipse.jdt.apt.ui,
org.eclipse.jdt.compiler.tool,
org.eclipse.jdt.core` but it is not an easy task.

Comment: You might be maybe better off by using Maven projects and marking Source roots manually or using Build Helper Maven Plugin

Comment: Unfortunately, the MavenHelper plugin is incompatible with my version of IntelliJ IDEA 13.1.4 (most current ATM)

Comment: I meant build-helper-maven-plugin, which is the maven way of marking sources roots. And MavenHelper IntelliJ plugin should be compatible.